# Identical code, different answers?

Tags: evaluation, symbolic

I'm having some trouble with identical code giving different answers. On a fresh kernel (MM 9.0.0.0, Windows 64-bit), running the same code, copy-paste, gives two different answers:

```
In[1]:= Integrate[
  E^(-ρ^2/2) ρ^(
   p + m + 1) (Δz^2 + ρ^2)^-(m + 1/2)
  , {ρ, 0, ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> {{m, p} ∈ Integers, m >= 0, 
    p >= 0, Δz > 0}] // FullSimplify

Out[1]= 1/2 π (2^(1/2 (1 - m + p))
 Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[1/2 + m, 1/2 (1 + m - p), Δz^2/2]
 - (Δz^(1 - m + p) Gamma[1/2 (2 + m + p)] 
Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[1/2 (2 + m + p), 1/2 (3 - m + p), Δz^2/2])/
   Gamma[1/2 + m]) Sec[1/2 (m - p) π]

In[2]:= Integrate[
  E^(-ρ^2/2) ρ^(
   p + m + 1) (Δz^2 + ρ^2)^-(m + 1/2)
  , {ρ, 0, ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> {{m, p} ∈ Integers, m >= 0, 
    p >= 0, Δz > 0}] // FullSimplify

Out[2]= 2^(1/2 (-1 - m + p))
  Gamma[1/2 (2 + m + p)] HypergeometricU[1/2 + m, 1/2 (1 + m - p), Δz^2/2]
```

Subsequent runs of the same code consistently churn out, as far as I can tell, the second expression.

To make things even weirder, the first answer contains a global factor of $$\sec\left(\frac\pi2(m-p)\right),$$ which is singular for $m-p$ an odd integer. This makes useless in half the cases covered in the assumptions I explicitly gave to Integrate (`{m, p} ∈ Integers, m >= 0, p >= 0`).

I also get analogous behaviour, with a slightly different first answer, if I drop the `FullSimplify`.

Could someone shed some light on this?

Comment: The second evaluation is using cached values. If you use `ClearSystemCache[]`  before each evaluation you get the first result repeatedly [see ClearSystemCache](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ClearSystemCache.html)

Comment: @Nasser, I get 0 when I run `FullSimplify[% - %%, 
 Assumptions -> {{m, p} \[Element] Integers, m >= 0, 
   p >= 0, \[CapitalDelta]z > 0}]`.

Comment: @kguler I can see how clearing the cache would make it revert to the first result. I can't see why it wouldn't use those results the first time around, though.

Comment: @episanty,  I can't see why either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second and subsequent evaluations of the same expression are using cached values.If you use `ClearSystemCache[]` before each evaluation you get the first result repeatedly. (see [ClearSystemCache](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ClearSystemCache.html))

```
ClearSystemCache[];
Integrate[E^(-\[Rho]^2/2) \[Rho]^(p + m + 1) (\[CapitalDelta]z^2 + \[Rho]^2)^-(m + 1/2),
{\[Rho],  0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> {{m, p} \[Element] Integers, 
m >= 0, p >= 0, \[CapitalDelta]z > 0}] // FullSimplify
```

gives

[image]

Evaluating the expression second time:

```
 Integrate[E^(-\[Rho]^2/2) \[Rho]^(p + m + 1) (\[CapitalDelta]z^2 + \[Rho]^2)^-(m + 1/2), 
 {\[Rho],  0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> {{m, p} \[Element] Integers, 
 m >= 0, p >= 0, \[CapitalDelta]z > 0}] // FullSimplify
```

gives

[image]

and

```
 FullSimplify[% - %%, Assumptions -> {{m, p} \[Element] Integers, 
   m >= 0, p >= 0, \[CapitalDelta]z > 0}]
```

gives `0.`

Finally, if you repeat the assumptions of `Integrate` inside `FullSimplify`

```
ClearSystemCache[];
Integrate[ E^(-\[Rho]^2/2) \[Rho]^(p + m +  1) (\[CapitalDelta]z^2 + \[Rho]^2)^-(m + 1/2), 
 {\[Rho], 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> {{m, p} \[Element] Integers,
  m >= 0,  p >= 0, \[CapitalDelta]z > 0}] // 
 FullSimplify[#,  Assumptions -> {{m, p} \[Element] Integers, m >= 0, 
 p >= 0, \[CapitalDelta]z > 0}] &
```

you get the output

[image]

directly (without having to re-evaluate `Integrate[...]`).